# Opendaylight don´t detect Zodiax FX

Tags: opendaylight

My ODL controller detect my Zodiac FX switches randomly when he wants, and in the most of the cases Zodiac isn´t detected, the ports and IP´s are well defined.

There is any way to scan better the connected switches with ODL? (I have tried to switch on Zodiac before and after of start ODL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is openflow? if so, aren't you telling the Zodiac switch which IP to
connect to? That point, when/if the switch connects on the openflow
port to OpenDaylight, is when it will be discovered. There is no "scanning"
from OpenDaylight's side.